# Server 'connect()' function in qt

Tags: c++, qt, unix, server

I need to do a server based application in Qt in which basically I have a map and every client that connects to the server will represent a car on that map. There will be different speed limits on the map and a client can send different data to the server like reporting an accident (which will be transmitted to all connected clients), asking for news etc.

The problem is, I only have to use the functions available in C++, more specifically I need to create the server and client in C++. That means I have to use the 'connect()' function to establish a connection between the server and the client, but the problem is, when I try to call the function like this:

```
if (connect(sockDesc, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(sockaddr)) == -1)
```

It gives me the following error: error: no matching function for call to ‘MainWindow::connect(int&, sockaddr*, long unsigned int)’

Does it have something to do with the 'connect()' function used by Qt for signals & slots? Or is there something else? Thank you.

Comment: QT is written in C++, not C. C is a different language, you cannot write QT applications in C.

Comment: You're right, my fault. I meant in c++.

Comment: You can use `::connect` to refer to the global function, rather than the member function on `MainWindow`.

Comment: It worked! I never really thought about that, thank you very much, @AlanStokes! :)